# Scratch file used for Merge step in ArcGIS (10.3.1) Model does not keep all fields of input files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, merge, dissolve

I am using a nested model to merge a large number of Shapefiles, then dissolving them based on a specific attribute. The solution to this was outlined in another question ([Dissolving shapefile but retain attribute fields using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160008/dissolving-shapefile-but-retain-attribute-fields-using-arcgis-desktop)). But if I use the option to store the Merge result as a scratch file, all my fields but one are not in that file, so my end result when I try to spatially join the Merge result to get my fields back is that - of course - they aren't there. But, if I specify a permanent Shapefile for the Merge step, and use that as my input to the Dissolve step, all my original fields are there in my final result. Is there some step I am missing or is there a bug in the use of a scratch file for my Merge step?